# easy calculus question about intervals and integers

Tags: calculus

Let $N = \{ \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \} $. Consider the interval $I = (-1,1) \setminus N $.

Question: Can we find an open interval $O$ around $0 \in I$ so that $O \subset I $ ???

Comment: Is 0 an isolated point? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because if were could, there would exist an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \subset I$. But no such $\epsilon$ can exist, because ... and I hope you can fill in this part.

Comment: Is it because by the archimidean property we have that $\frac{1}{n}  < \epsilon $ ?